# Term to describe pre-canned objects for use in testing

Tags: testing, terminology

I have forgotten the term for a class that provides pre-canned objects for use as test data.

e.g. If I'm testing a payment module and I need credit card objects of different types, I might have a class in my test scope called `CreditCard__something__` with static members or factory methods for creating cards of different flavours.

What is this term?

Comment: Collections of pre-created objects for testing purposes are variously called stubs, fakes and mocks (depending on their specific use).

Comment: None of those terms mean what I have described. In particular, none of them are a repository of (or factory for) instances of domain objects.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixtures.

The setUp and tearDown methods are for creating or cleaning up your fixtures. If they live in memory, cleanup is easy, but if your fixtures live in the database, then both setting them up and tearing them down can be a little more involved.

Comment: Thanks. I busted my brain for several hours and finally remembered. Glad you have confirmed it for me. Cheers!